# Can Reflection work between two WARS running under the same process?

Tags: java, reflection

Assume I have multiple WAR files deployed under a [wrapper](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html), all the WARs run under the same process. Can I use reflection to access class information between different WARs?

I know that of course we can't use Reflection between two independent processes. But what about the scenario I described?

Comment: Some containers may allow it, but according to the spec, the answer is no.  Each .war is an independently deployed web application, and the class loader of one .war should not have access to the classes in another.

Comment: @VGR So is it a limitation in Java or does it solely depend on the container? If you could link any material it would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Actually, now that I’m reading about the Java Service Wrapper more, I realize I was hasty in assuming that you were deploying to a Java EE container or web container.  It seems the Java Service Wrapper can wrap many things.  What sort of container are you using to serve your .war files?

Comment: @VGR Jboss 7.2.5

Comment: My understanding is that JBoss uses a “unified classloader,” which would in fact permit one .war to access classes in another .war.  This is in violation of the Java Servlet Specification, but in my past experience, JBoss seems to like playing fast and loose with specifications.  It’s possible JBoss doesn’t use it anymore;  I haven’t worked with JBoss in many years.

Comment: @VGR with enough reflections you can always access classes from another .jar .war whatever, as long as this is running on single JVM.

Comment: @GotoFinal And how will your code find the other .war?  Hard-code the path?  Deployed .war files are often exploded by containers into unpredictable places.  Not that hard-coding the path would be a good idea even if the path were known.

Comment: @VGR You can try to find any reference to any class/class loader in internals of jboss  (and if parallel class loader is used you can get all loader at runtime with a bit of reflection too) or just add instrumentation at runtime and get all the classes and look for whatever you want.

Comment: @VGR and I'm definitely not telling that this is a good idea, just that it is possible.

Comment: @prettyvoid can I ask why you need this? As anyways this is pretty bad idea to use reflections like that, that the whole idea of using servers like that. And if you want more exact answer than comments above, then it would be nice to get some example that I could actually run and test.